# Why my own stream is not emitting any value when I use StreamController?

Tags: dart

```
class MyStream extends Stream<int> {
  final int start;
  final int end;

  MyStream(this.start, this.end);

  @override
  StreamSubscription<int> listen(void Function(int event) onData, {Function onError, VoidCallback onDone, bool cancelOnError}) {
    final controller = StreamController<int>();
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      controller.sink.add(i);
    }

    return controller.stream.listen(onData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: cancelOnError);
  }
}
```

And I am listening to it using:

```
MyStream(4, 1).listen((event) => print(event));
```

But it doesn't print anything. I think I must be doing something silly.

---

**PS:**

I know I can use `Stream.fromIterable(...)` instead of creating a `StreamController` with `for` loop and that solution works but why by using `StreamController` I am not able to make it generate numbers? What should be the solution then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't print anything because the start is greater than the end, so the loop will never run.
Try doing this instead:

```dart
MyStream(1, 4).listen((event) => print(event));
```

It will print the numbers from 1 to 4.